# Vue.js how to keep the todo when the no keep it button (cancel button) is clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
 <template>
 <div>
  <p class="tasks">Completed Tasks: {{todos.filter(todo => {return todo.done === true}).length}}</p>
 <p class="tasks">Pending Tasks: {{todos.filter(todo => {return todo.done === false}).length}}</p>
 <todo v-on:delete-todo="deleteTodo" v-on:complete-todo="completeTodo" v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id"  v-bind:todo="todo"></todo>
 </div>
</template>


<script>

import Todo from './Todo';
export default {
name:'Myapp',
props: ['todos'],
components:{
Todo,
},
methods: {

deleteTodo(todo) {
   this.$swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You can\'t revert your action',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, Keep it!',
    showCloseButton: true,


   }).then((result) => {
     const todoIndex = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
     this.todos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
     if (result.value){
       this.$swal('Deleted!', 'Your Todo has been deleted', 'success')
     }
     else{
       this.$swal('Canceled', 'Your Todo is still in place', 'info')
     }

   });
},

completeTodo(todo) {
  const todoIndex = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
  this.todos[todoIndex].done = true;
  this.$swal('Success', 'Todo Completed!', 'success');
},
}
```

};

I am new to vue.js and this is my first project in vue. Basically everything works fine but i would like to achieve one thing which is when the user clicks on no keep it(cancel button) or the close button the todo should not be deleted but i am finding it difficult achieving that at the moment.

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<h1 class="ui dividing centered header">Vue.js Todo App</h1>
<div class='ui three column centered grid'>
  <div class='column'>
    <myapp v-bind:todos="todos"></myapp>
    <add-todo v-on:add-todo="addTodo"></add-todo>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

 </template>

<script>

 import Myapp from './components/Myapp';
 import Todo from './components/Todo';
 import AddTodo from './components/AddTodo';

 export default {
 name: 'App',

 components:{
Myapp,
Todo,
AddTodo,
},
methods: {
addTodo(newTodo){
this.todos.push(newTodo);

}
},

data:function () {
return {
  todos: [{
    title: 'Project 1',
    project: 'School',
    done: true,
  }, {
    title: 'Project 2',
    project: 'Mosque',
    done: true,
  }, {
    title: 'Project 3',
    project: 'Bank',
    done: false,
  },
    {
    title: 'Project 4',
    project: 'Hospital',
    done: false,
  },
  {
    title: 'Project 5',
    project: 'Church',
    done: false,
  }],
  }

}
};
</script>
```

root vue component that is passing the props to the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your Sweet Alert promise.

You are splicing the todos whether the confirm or cancel button was clicked.

Move your splicing into the `if(result.value)` condition and you should be ok.

```
deleteTodo(todo) {
    this.$swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'You can\'t revert your action',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, Keep it!',
        showCloseButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            const todoIndex = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
            this.todos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
            this.$swal('Deleted!', 'Your Todo has been deleted', 'success')
        }
        else{
            this.$swal('Canceled', 'Your Todo is still in place', 'info')
        }

    });
},
```

Comment: can you help me further with the $emit method? I  do not quite get it from the documentation and how to pass the data from the child to the parent component in order for the todo not  to be deleted. I know props work from parent to child.

Comment: Do you have a root vue component that is passing the props to this component? Can you show the code?

Comment: Yes i do.. let me add it as an edit to the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example that may help you.

Comment: @ CUGreen it still did not solve the problem. The todo  still gets deleted when the user clicks on the cancel button.

Comment: @CUGreen..great i totally forgot to try that.. it is working as expected..since it is a static data in my main component how do i go about retrieving  data from let say a server and update the todo accordingly?